# How do I get to my Ubuntu partition?

Tags: boot, partitioning

Basically this tragic story has been told before around here. I installed Ubuntu on a partition on my hard drive but it corrupted my windows when it resized. Luckily for me there was a tiny factory image partition with all of windows ON it. I used that to reinstall windows back on the partition.

So on my computer I have three partitions on my harddrive:
Windows Recovery
Windows
Ubuntu

Heres the problem: When I used the Recovery to re-install windows I am now unable to get to my ubuntu partition. I have tried all the options on the boot menu and none of them lead to Ubuntu.

How do I get to ubuntu again? I have a disk with ubuntu installed on it.

Comment: Does [RecoveringUbuntuAfterInstallingWindows](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/RecoveringUbuntuAfterInstallingWindows) in the Ubuntu wiki help at all? If not, tell us which of these steps you've tried, if any.

Answer (score 2):

You will have to recover grub. That is the way I recommend:

I never got in trouble by using these instructions:
https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Grub2#Recover

First of all, you must start your system from a live cd. Then

"**METHOD 3 - CHROOT**

This method of installation uses the chroot command to gain access to the broken system's files. Once the chroot command is issued, the LiveCD treats the broken system's / as its own. Commands run in a chroot environment will affect the broken systems filesystems and not those of the LiveCD.

**1)** Boot to the LiveCD Desktop (Ubuntu 9.10 or later). Please note that the Live CD must be the same as the system you are fixing - either 32-bit or 64-bit (if not then the chroot will fail).

**2)** Open a terminal (Applications > Accessories > Terminal).

**3)** Determine your normal system partition - (the switch is a lowercase "L")

```
sudo fdisk -l
```

If you aren't sure, run

```
df -Th
```

Look for the correct disk size and ext3 or ext4 format.

**4)** Mount your normal system partition:

Substitute the correct partition: sda1, sdb5, etc.

```
sudo mount /dev/sdXX /mnt
```

*Example: sudo mount /dev/sda1 /mnt*

**5)** Only if you have a separate boot partition:
sdYY is the /boot partition designation (for example sdb3)

```
sudo mount /dev/sdYY /mnt/boot
```

**6)**
Mount the critical virtual filesystems:

```
sudo mount --bind /dev  /mnt/dev
sudo mount --bind /dev/pts  /mnt/dev/pts
sudo mount --bind /proc /mnt/proc
sudo mount --bind /sys  /mnt/sys
```

**7)**
Chroot into your normal system device:

```
sudo chroot /mnt
```

**8)** If there is no /boot/grub/grub.cfg or it's not correct, create one using

```
update-grub
```

**9)**
Reinstall GRUB 2:

Substitute the correct device - sda, sdb, etc. Do not specify a partition number.

```
grub-install /dev/sdX
```

**10)** Verify the install (use the correct device, for example sda. Do not specify a partition):

```
sudo grub-install --recheck /dev/sdX
```

**11)**
Exit chroot: CTRL-D on keyboard

**12)**
Unmount virtual filesystems:

```
sudo umount /mnt/dev/pts
sudo umount /mnt/dev
sudo umount /mnt/proc
sudo umount /mnt/sys
```

**13)**
If you mounted a separate /boot partition:

```
sudo umount /mnt/boot
```

**14)**
Unmount the LiveCD's /usr directory:

```
sudo umount /mnt/usr
```

**15)**
Unmount last device:

```
sudo umount /mnt
```

**16)**
Reboot.

```
sudo reboot
```

"

Comment: Doesn't that Windows recovery thing recreate the partition table though?

Comment: It seems like yes.